# Logarithms Problem, when finding $x^n = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Why is it that $1^4 = 1$, when using log laws why do you get $3 = \frac {\ln1}{\ln1} = 1 \therefore 2 = 0$? I was trying to show that $(-1)^{2^x + 1} = -1$, given $x \geq 0 $ and is an integer, but using the logarithms I got $2^x = 0$ which doesn't yield a value of x.

How can I prove that it is true?

Comment: Because $\ln(1) / \ln(1)$ is nonsense.

Comment: What do you mean @T.Bongers?

Comment: What is $\ln(1)$? Does it make sense to divide with it?

Comment: Ok, I see. How do you then prove it to be true?

Comment: Prove what, exactly? That $(-1)^{2^x + 1} = -1$? This is true for some values of $x$, false for others, and needs careful definition for others still. If $x$ is an integer, this is a trivial consequence of the fact that $(-1)^2 = 1$.

Comment: $(-1)^{2^x+1} = -1$ is true whenever $2^x+1$ is odd, which is true if x is any natural number or 0. This cannot be solved logarithmically, as you cannot take a logarithm using a negative base.

Comment: Ok, how do you prove it then @TreeHouse196 using algebra? What values it it false for @T.Bongers? Given that $x \geq 0$ and is an integer

Comment: @frog1944 I strongly suggest taking a few minutes to carefully consider, rather than rapid-fire comments; if you just try a few values of $x$ that aren't integers, you'll see the issues that arise (and *please* state all the assumptions in the original question; the fact that $x$ is an integer is important).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mathematically:**

$(-1)^{2^x+1}=-1\implies$

$2^x+1\equiv1\pmod2\implies$

$2^x\equiv0\pmod2\implies$

$x\in\mathbb{N}$

---

**In words:**

$(-1)^{2^x+1}=-1\implies$

$2^x+1\text{ is odd}\implies$

$2^x\text{ is even}\implies$

$x\text{ is any positive integer}$

Comment: I'm not sure if people in precalculus know modular arithmetic though

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda: That's why I've added the "**In words**" section.

Comment: Yes my comment was from before. It took a while to upload...

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda: Well, to be honest, I added that before I noticed the precalculus tag (reading some of the notions made in the question, I realized that it might be better off explained in words).